# why is the header for the JSON RPC interface text/plain? vs application/json?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

the [bitcoin core docs](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#remote-procedure-calls-rpcs) call out that `RPC HTTP requests must include a Content-Type header set to text/plain` and all the example commands confirm this header. why is it `text/plain` instead of `application/json`?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug, you should report it.